# ios make the SDK

Tags: ios, sdk

By the way, if you make your own SDK and someone adds an exception where there is an error, you can jump to the source code in the SDK. For example, if someone integrates your SDK but does not add a bundle package, it will report an error when integrating and jump to the source code in the SDK. How can you set the SDK to report an error but not jump to the source code in the SDK

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "someone adds an exception where there is an error"?

Comment: The SDK I gave him included the bundle package, but he didn't add the bundle package when he integrated it, so when it runs it will report an error, and at this point it will break to the source code, and I want to know if there is a way that it won't crash to the source code. I'm sorry, I used Google translation, I don't know if some parts of the expression is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If someone make critical error with integrating your SDK, best way make exception with correct description (e.g. with link to issue/guide in github).
This is better than getting unstable behavior. Do not be afraid crash, if it is clear.

Btw you can check debug mode and make crash only in debuging

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am now worried about the breakpoint to the source code when the program crashes, and I don't want my source code to be seen by others

Comment: It depend on way distribution your SDK. You can make binary library. https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework